# How do all these web platforms achieve a long-time login session that does not require the user to login over and over again?

Tags: php, session, authentication, persistence

I really don't get that: Some platforms have some kind of "persistent" login sessions. Like Stackoverflow and many other boards and platforms. I've logged in here a month ago. And even if I quit my browser totally and have another internet connection with different IP, I come back here with no login.

I can't belief that's just done with cookies, since cookies are not accepted in most modern browsers anymore (they would ask the user and the click instinctive "no").

I even encountered a platform that does persistent login regardless of the browser I use. I could use safari, or opera. No matter what. I was always logged in with my nick.

Since a few years have passed since that and I went totally off from web development, I wonder if technologies have changed? How is that done today?

Comment: I would encourage people not to vote down the question just because the author makes an unreasonable assumption.  It's not a bad question... it's a very reasonable one, in fact.

Answer (score 7):

> I can't belief[sic] that's just done with
>   cookies, since cookies are not
>   accepted in most modern browsers
>   anymore (they would ask the user and
>   the click instinctive "no").

Every major browser accepts cookies by default.

<sub>(Just another example of the golden rule of rationality:
Beliefs do not substitute facts.)</sub>

Answer (score 7):

Most browsers are configured to accept first-party cookies by default - these are cookies supplied by a website for the same domain. However, a [*third party*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Third-party_cookies) cookie, one sent by one site, but destined to be used on another, will often be rejected or pop open a confirmation dialog.

So the answer is, yes, it is cookie!

There's some [interesting graphs here](http://www.grc.com/cookies/stats.htm) showing the percentage of visitors to one site who have various forms of cookie filtering enabled, broken down by browser:

[image]

The same site also has a [summary of the capabilities and defaults for cookie handling](http://www.grc.com/cookies/fameandshame.htm) in the major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies make the world go round.

Answer (score 1):

so... it seems you have your answer (or at least part of it), but I thought I'd add the detail (though I suspect you already know this), that you can set a cookie to expire at some point in the distant future, effectively making it permanent.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check that StackOverflow stores cookies in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

### Cookies

Like Paul Dixon pointed out cookies are still accepted by the browser in some sort of fashion.

### PHP Sessions and cookies.

In php this is most of the times done with sessions which default stores files on server to keep track of user and sents a cookie-header to store a cookie on the browser.

Read more about it from this [zend tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/646)

### PHP Session-id prepended to url

It can also be done by appending session-id to url instead of using cookies.

```
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0) // don't use cookies
```